# Как на стене разместить ссылку на группу, используя вики-разметку ВКонтакте?

Tags: вконтакте

Можно ли как-то запостить на стену ВКонтакте ссылку на группу, но не как внешнюю ссылку, а используя подобие викии-разметки?

Стандартная ВК вики-разметка, похоже, не работает, и [[public12345]] не преобразуется на стене в ссылку на группу.

Не хочется публиковать как http://vk.com/названиегруппы из-за капчи, которая стала часто появляться при постинге со ссылкой.

Может, есть недокументированные способы задействовать вики-разметку в обычном посте на стену?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По каким соображениям минусуют вопрос, не понятно.

Нашел недокументированный (?) способ. В пост нужно вставить дублирующийся вики-код:

```
[[public555555|public555555| Текст ссылки ]]
```

Может, кому-то пригодится. Хотя частоту появления капчи это, похоже, не сильно снижает.

Comment: Ответить почему минусуют?

Да вопрос вообще не по теме.

На  vk.com есть подробная документация по разметке "Помощь по разметке страницы" там написано все простым языком.

Comment: @Shrek, вопрос-то не про страницы, а про Стену, где вики-разметка не работает никак. Почему все наискосок невнимательны?

Comment: Проще написать `@club101010`, и нажать `Enter`, после чего можно изменить текст ссылки.

Comment: сейчас-то да. Вопрос 2012 года ; )